# Extending django modelform with selected action-items

Tags: django, view, action, admin

In my application, I have a set of players who may be a member of (at most) one team. I am implementing a custom action in the player admin view where I select players and create a new team with those players, following the example at: www.jpichon.net/blog/2010/08/django-admin-actions-and-intermediate-pages/

However, I'm sensing that there should be a less django-intrusive way of implementing this than using a fully customized template. What I'm thinking is: can the normal ModelForm for the Team class be extended to accept arguments when coming from the create team action? I struggle to find some documentation on the subject though.

This is a screenshot of what I have so far (following the above guide):

[image]

Which I would like to result in something like:

[image]

The first part works fine when using the custom template, but I cant figure out how to (nicely) extend the existing admin page for Teams to accept the player arguments from the actions. I suppose the third step (after clicking the 'Create Team' button) can be accomplished by overriding the save() method of the Team Modelform?

Thankful for any assistance!